# Multiple entries on the free-entry visa (Indonesia)

Tags: multiple-entry, visa-free-entry, indonesia

I am looking for information on whether the free-entry visa for Indonesia allows for multiple entries within those 30 days? I am traveling to Bali next week and will stay there for 2 weeks before going to Australia for a week and then back to Bali for 5 days.

Will the Indonesian visa allow for multiple entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, each Indonesian admission stamp is **a single entry** admission, i.e. it only allows a "single entry for up to 30 days maximum". Once  you leave - even if before your 30 days are up - your admission is done.

Next time you arrive you get another single entry admission stamp which again is good for another 30 days.

To my knowledge currently there are no restrictions on the number of times you can do this, nor there's any "cooling off" required period between stays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If for some reason this is not the case, I will update this thread and mark my own answer as the real one. Of course, I hope that is not the case :-D

Answer (score 1):

[image: Indonesia visa exemption]

Here's what a visa **exemption** (ie, this is not a visa) stamp looks like. It says:

> Permitted to enter and stay for 30 days from date shown above.
>   Work prohibited
>   Not extendable

This is a one-time thing. You enter, can stay up to 30 days, and leave. When you do, you get an exit stamp (not shown in photo, but the blue trace top left is part of the exit stamp, a triangle).

If you want to come again, you'll get another visa exemption. There's no cool-off period, and Indonesian Immigration officers don't really care, unless you're doing repeated back-to-back 30-day stays.

Comment: Thanks also for your answer, I marked George's answer as the correct one even though yours is too. Merely because he answered first.